# Compile Error C2365

Tags: c++, qt5

I have some data members in a class:

```
class MyClass {
   ...
   QComboBox *cb1, *cb2, *cb3;
   ...
   public:
   ...
   // Getters
   int cb1() const;
   int cb2() const;
   int cb3() const;
   ...
}
```

When I try to compile, I get a `C2365 compile error` saying

> 'data member' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data member'.

How can I fix it, please? I see in every libraries documentation that getters always have the same name as the variable they are meant for. What's the trick?

Comment: You can't have a member function with the same name as a member variable.

Comment: *in every libraries documentation that getters always have the same name as the variable they are meant for.* then you need to read different or more specifically, *better*, documentation. Such claims are nonsense. Just name your variables `_cb1` or `Cb1` or whatever you desire as long as you stick to the same rule I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your code in something like:

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    QComboBox *m_cb1;
    QComboBox *m_cb2;
    QComboBox *m_cb3;
    ...
public:
    ...
    // Getters
    int cb1() const;
    int cb2() const;
    int cb3() const;
    ...
}
```

As Joachim Pileborg pointed out you have a name collision in your snippet

Comment: No need to point me -1, I never usually use that kind of naming, I was just wondering how it is possible. Qt documentation use that kind of naming (unless I am making a mistake) and you know how popular Qt is

Comment: @Patrik that's not a Qt releated thing... it's just C++ rule. I've not downcasted you just explained the reason of the mistake